# What is the difference between instanceShape and resourceShape?

Tags: uri, oslc

What is the difference between instanceShape and  resourceShape in terms of OSLC 2.0 Specification?

> **oslc:instanceShape**    - The URI of a Resource Shape that describes the
>   possible properties, occurrence, value types, allowed values and
>   labels. This shape information is useful in displaying the subject
>   resource as well as guiding clients in performing modifications.
>   Instance shapes may be specific to the authenticated user associated
>   with the request that retrieved the resource, the current state of the
>   resource and other factors and thus should not be cached.
>
> **Resource Shape** - meet this need by providing a machine-readable definition of one or more OSLC resource types or instances. An OSLC
>   Creation Factory MAY provide one or more Resource Shapes so that you
>   know what properties are allowed and required to create resources.

So the my understanding is that resource describes the what the properties are,but **isntanceShape** is just the URL to the resource shape?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** `oslc:instanceShape` links to a resource shape for the current resource, and `oslc:resourceShape` links to a resource shape for the resources that can be created or queried in that context.

---

### oslc:instanceShape

`oslc:instanceShape` (an RDF property or "predicate") is used to link to a Resource Shape "that describes the possible properties, occurrence, value types, allowed values and labels" *of the current resource*. That is, if you have a [link (aka 'triple')](http://www.robertprice.co.uk/robblog/2004/10/what_is_an_rdf_triple_-shtml/) like this:

```
<http://example.com/resources/1> oslc:instanceShape <http://example.com/shapes/A>
```

then that is stating that the resource shape that can be retrived by requesting `http://example.com/shapes/A` describes the shape of the resource identified by the URI `http://example.com/resources/1`. (You would probably see this link in the response to a request on that resource's URI `http://example.com/resources/1`).

### oslc:instanceShape vs "Resource Shape"

So if you are asking "what is the difference between `oslc:instanceShape` and the phrase 'Resource Shape'?", the answer is that `oslc:instanceShape` is the property/predicate that is used to link to a "Resource Shape".

### oslc:resourceShape

However, there is also another property/predicate called `oslc:resourceShape`, which you mention. This is used to link from a "Creation Factory" or "Query Capability" resource to describe the 'shape' of the resources that the factory or capability deals with. That is, it links to a Resource Shape "that describes the possible properties, occurrence, value types, allowed values and labels" *of the resources that can be created or queried* in that context.

### oslc:instanceShape vs oslc:resourceShape

In theory, it would be possible for a creation factory to have both of these links, e.g.:

```
<http://example.com/types/1/factory> rdf:type oslc:CreationFactory.
<http://example.com/types/1/factory> oslc:resourceShape <http://example.com/types/1/shape>.
<http://example.com/types/1/factory> oslc:instanceShape <http://example.com/factoryShape>.
```

Where requesting `http://example.com/types/1/shape` would return a resource shape that describes the 'shape' of resources that the creation factory `http://example.com/types/1/factory` can create, and requesting `http://example.com/factoryShape` would return a shape that describes the properties that can appear on the creation factory resource itself. (However, it is quite unlikely that a creation factory resource would have an `instanceShape` link, as its properties are well-defined by the OSLC specification and I can't think of any cases where the client would either need to display these to a user or modify them.)

**Conclusion: `oslc:instanceShape` links to a resource shape for the current resource, and `oslc:resourceShape` links to a resource shape for the resources that can be created or queried in that context.**

---

#### Aside: oslc:resourceShape vs oslc:ResourceShape

Slight aside: `oslc:resourceShape` and `oslc:ResourceShape` are different: `oslc:resourceShape` is a property to link to a resource shape, and `oslc:ResourceShape` is a value to use for the `rdf:type` on Resource Shape resources themselves.

#### Source

The [resource table for the CreationFactory type](http://open-services.net/bin/view/Main/OslcCoreSpecification#Resource_Creation_Factory) says, for the `oslc:resourceShape` property: "A Creation Factory MAY provide Resource Shapes that describe shapes of resources that may be created".

The OSLC specs don't seem to include a clear description of how `oslc:instanceShape` is different, but [the submission of OSLC Resource Shapes to the W3C](http://www.w3.org/Submission/2014/SUBM-shapes-20140211/#instanceShape) says: "The oslc:instanceShape property is used to link any described resource with a shape resource that describes its contents".